# Where can I see upstream messages in the Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I started using Firebase Messaging recently and I want one of the clients to generate a notification that can be sent to the other users with the app
so by sending a message upstream to server and then from there sending it to other devices with app seemed a solution

where can I see my firebase upstream messages on the firebase console

```
public class FirebaseNotifier extends FirebaseMessagingService {

static FirebaseMessaging fmst;
static FirebaseInstanceId fid;
static Button b1;



public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    sendNotification(remoteMessage);
}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    int icon = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) ? R.drawable.myicon : R.drawable.myicon;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getFrom())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}


public static void sendEm(AtomicInteger msid,String fms) {


    fmst=MainActivity.fms;



            fmst.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(fms + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
                    .setMessageId(Integer.toString(msid.incrementAndGet()))
                    .addData("my_message", "fhdhchj")
                    .addData("my_action", "SAY_HELLO")
                    .build());



}

@Override
public void onMessageSent(String s) {
    super.onMessageSent(s);
    Log.i("Message is:", "" + s);
}

public void onSendError(String msgID, Exception exception) {

    Log.i("message id id:"+msgID,"Exception:"+ exception.getMessage());
}
}
```

and I'm calling this from main with a button

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


static EditText et;
Button b1;
static FirebaseMessaging fms;
static  String senderid="";
static  AtomicInteger msgId;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    msgId= new AtomicInteger(1);



    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    fms=FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();



    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FirebaseNotifier.sendEm(msgId, fms.toString());

        }
    });




}



private boolean Validate(EditText et) {


    if(et.getText().toString().length()>0) return true;
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}





}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to receive messages sent with the upstream API you need to implement an XMPP server.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-the-xmpp-connection-server-protocol

Your XMPP server can then receive the upstream messages and send the notifications to the other devices.

Comment: Thankyou, but where to I write that code on server side?

Comment: You need to implement a custom server. Deploy can happen on any cloud provider or in house server.